# Upgrading new PC to Win 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I just bought a new Dell Win 8.1 PC last week. I want to upgrade it to Win 10.

For some reason, the Get Windows 10 App is not appearing in the tray, nor the GWX process in the task manager. I downloaded the troubleshooter from the [Windows KB topic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3081048). It says that my version of windows is not up to date:

> The Get Windows 10 App is only for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows 8.1 users.

For Detection Details, it says I am running Windows Version 6.3 (which is 8.1, as confirmed in Control Panel->System); I am running 64 bit Windows 8.1, not Enterprise.

I have downloaded, installed updates, and restarted 3 times, totaling about 150 updates, and the only one I haven't installed is the skype app update. So Windows Update (from the control panel) thinks I'm up to date. I've changed update settings a few times, getting and installing more and more update options, until it finally says:

> No updates are available.

Most recent check for updates was 1 minute ago (2:49 PM EST).

I have checked to ensure that I have [Win 8.1's latest update](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/install-latest-update-windows-8-1). I am not running Enterprise Edition.

This is a brand new PC. On my older 8.1 (with worse specs), I had no issues.

**What step(s) am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem (couldn't install *Get Windows 10* app), but I used Windows Media Creation tool and upgraded from 8.1 to 10 there.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

**64 Bit download** - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616936

> IMPORTANT: To upgrade for free, select Upgrade this PC now in the
>   tool. You should NOT be asked for a product key during the upgrade
>   process. If you create a USB and use it to install, make sure to
>   remove the USB as soon as setup begins. If you don't, you may be
>   prompted for a product key. If this happens, remove the USB and
>   restart your PC to continue with setup.

After upgrading this way you can still do a rollback to previous version and you don't need any external drives or separate partitions to install.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a shot! Glad I'm not the only one with this issue.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting, It didn't work ?

Comment: Not me. It did and I just got back to this site. :) You have my +1

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked through all of your installed updates to see if update **KB3035583** is installed? That is the update that gives you the tray icon, asking if you would like to reserve a copy of Windows 10.

You can [see which updates are installed](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/which-windows-updates-installed#1TC=windows-7), and check for the corresponding update mentioned above.

Alternatively, you could do the update manually, by visiting Microsoft's [website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

Comment: `wmic qfe | find "KB3035583"` outputs today's date. So I believe I do have it installed. Edit: and Installed Updates also shows it installed.

Comment: @Josiah I'm guessing rebooting the computer didn't help eh? Sometimes it may be a bit slow to start the upgrade offer in the system tray.

Comment: Nope, I've rebooted a few times since then.

Comment: @Josiah darn the luck. Have you tried the manual upgrade like rudolf323 and I have mentioned? If you did, did it throw any errors?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying it now, 22%...

Comment: The manual upgrade did work - thanks for the help!